# how do I only strikethrough one letter in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to do a strike-through text effect for one letter.

How could I achieve that with CSS or HTML?

Comment: Please post your relevant code, as well as an explanation of what you tried and in what way your own code failed. See: "*[mcve]*" code, "*[ask]*" and take the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<s>` element:

```
Parad<s>o</s>x Jewelz
```

Or inline-style, or create a css class for letter o only, see the example below

```css
.strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<p>Parad<s>o</s>x Jewelz</p>

<p>Parad<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">o</span>x Jewelz</p>

<p>Parad<span class="strikethrough">o</span>x Jewelz</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS attribute `text-decoration` and value `line-through`.

```css
.strikethrough{
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
<p>Parad<span class="strikethrough">o</span>x Jewelz</p>
```

Or you can simply use the `<s>` element

```html
Parad<s>o</s>x Jewelz
```

Or `<strikethrough>`, although that's obsolete (why type more characters when you don't need to?)

Comment: Just use the `<s>o</s>` element correctly.